# How to index a dictionary in solr

Tags: solr

I have a field in solr `schema.xml`, `course_category_score`. I want this field to be indexed in solr as dictionary. For example:

```
course_category_score{
         'engineering': 1.6,
         'management':2.0
}
```

I want this field for sorting purpose also.

Answer (score 1):

In order to index any object including a dictionary, the object can be JSON serialized and indexed as a normal string field.

```
doc.Add("FieldName", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary));
```

Field definition:

```
<field
        name= "FieldName"
        type= "string"
        stored= "true"
        indexed= "false"
        required= "false"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
solrURL = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/<SchemaName>', timeout=100) 
dictData = {} #Your any dictionary
solrURL.add([dictData])
solrURL.commit()
```

This would be a schemaless ingestion of the given dictionary.

Comment: Thanks zorze, but I need to add dictionary without using pysolr. Want to get it done directly from solr DataImportHandler.